# Java Applet Integration

Tags: force.com

Good morning SE !

I made some progress related to the applet. The issue is tricky because it concerns at the same time Java Web Service and Salesforce architecture.

For the context, it's a java applet serving e-id card reading purposes in Belgium. The architecture of the applet is as follow : 
[image: eid applet architecture]

The idea is to integrate the applet in a VFP. What I did until now is calling from a simple page as follow :

```
<apex:page>
<applet name="applet" width="600" height="300" code="be.fedict.eid.applet.Applet.class" codebase = "{!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}"
archive ="{!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}/eid-applet-package-1.2.6.jar, {!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}/eid-applet-service-1.2.6.jar,{!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}/eid-applet-service-cdi-1.2.6.jar,{!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}/eid-applet-service-signer-1.2.6.jar,{!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}/eid-applet-shared-1.2.6.jar,{!$Resource.eidAppletPackageZIP}/eid-applet-service-spi-1.2.6.jar"  alt="eID applet">
    <param name="AppletService" value="identification-service" />
    <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false" />
</applet>
```

*Why did I put so many jars in that archive ?* Because now I'm facing a RuntimeException, which I suspect is from the architecture of Salesforce.

Indeed the applet I'm referring is mostly used in a Java EE Web Application environment. You can see a live test in this [eid applet test link](https://www.e-contract.be/eid-applet-beta/identification.xhtml) which is hosted in the official company developing it. You should see "Please connect a card reader..." with a progress bar. I'm not even to that point. I reached that point [image: vfp_applet].

Someone had a [similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/eid-applet/9tRrf0XVMD0/yhQJL3U9ITsJ) but I don't see how I could duplicate his solution into Salesforce.

The source code of this is available [on their github](https://github.com/e-Contract/eid-applet/tree/master/eid-applet-test). The architecture of the webapp is different from Salesforce's one. The jars are directly available in their [maven repository](https://www.e-contract.be/maven2/be/fedict/eid-applet/eid-applet-sdk/1.2.6/). Download the sdk.zip and you'll find documentation as well.

As the manifest of the eid-applet-package doesn't allow .com url, I changed it to allow .com and resigned the jar. It is available in this [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbewc0p7451kelv/eid-applet-package-1.2.6.jar?dl=0).

My questions are :

Is it possible to run such an applet on the Salesforce platform ? And if yes, how ? So far my attempts haven't been succesful.

I'd be more than happy to provide more information if needed and I'm really interested in an explanation.